# An error occurred trying to download 'http://cardknox.com/cktest2.application'. Visual Studio

Tags: c#, html, clickonce, netlify

I have completed my .NET 4.8 project and now I want to build and publish it so that everyone can download and use it. My goal is to create a URL where users can download the application directly from their browser.

Here is the process I followed:

- I used ClickOnce to publish my project and entered a temporary/ fake URL during the publishing process.
- Once the publishing was complete, I gathered all the ClickOnce deployment files that were generated.
- I placed these deployment files into my HTML folder.
- Next, I uploaded the entire folder, including the deployment files, to Netlify.
- After the upload, I obtained the new URL provided by Netlify and replaced the temporary URL used during publishing in Visual Studio.
- I then republished the application using the updated URL ( https://solutionstesting.netlify.app/cktest2.htm).

However, when I click on the "Install" button, I get this error message

[image: error message]

I noticed that the application still seems to be pointing to the old fake URL, even though I updated it with the correct URL. Additionally, when I remove the "cktest2.htm" from the URL (leaving only `https://solutionstesting.netlify.app/`), it opens my HTML page but shows the same error message.

is there anything I'm missing?

HTML page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Download My App</title>
  <script>
    function downloadPrerequisite() {
      // Create a temporary link element
      var link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = "path/to/your/app/Prerequisites/dotnetfx48.exe"; // Replace with the path to your .NET Framework 4.8 setup file
      link.download = "dotnetfx48.exe";
      
      // Programmatically trigger the click event to start the download
      link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click"));
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Download My App</h1>
  <p>Please follow the instructions below to download and install my application.</p>
  
  <h2>Prerequisites</h2>
  <p>In order to run this application, you need to have the .NET Framework 4.8 installed on your computer. If you don't have it, click the button below to download and install it.</p>
  <button onclick="downloadPrerequisite()">Download .NET Framework 4.8</button>
  
  <h2>Download My App</h2>
  <p>Click the link below to download the application:</p>
  <a href="setup.exe">Download My App</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Netlify page: [netlify page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5aQl.png)

Please let me know if any additional files are needed